# Question related to the definition of affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

The definition for affine schemes I have learned was that it is a locally ringed space $(X, O_X)$ that is isomorphic to $(Spec \ A, O_{ Spec \ A })$ for some ring $A$ (commutative and includes $1$). Then, it follows that $A \cong O_X(X)$. Therefore, it follows that $(X, O_X)$ is isomorphic to $(Spec \ O_X(X), O_{ Spec \ O_X(X) })$. Say this isomorphism is given by $(\phi, \alpha)$ where $\phi$ is a homeomorphism and  $\alpha: O_{ Spec \ O_X(X)}  \rightarrow \phi_* O_X$.

We know that the global section of $(Spec \ O_X(X), O_{ Spec \ O_X(X) })$ is $O_X(X)$, which is the same as that of $(X, O_X)$.

My question is, does it follow from the definition of affine schemes that the map between the global sections induced by $\alpha$ be necessarily the identity map? Thanks!

Comment: No, the definition only requires the induced map on global sections to be an isomorphism. It does not have to be the identity.

Comment: Any automorphism of $O_X(X)$ is the induced on global sections of some such an isomorphism $\alpha$ $(\phi,\alpha)$.